# Query for get empty objects in MongoDB with Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, sentence

I have this object in my MongoDB:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "jdflores",
  groups: [
    {
       name: "Group1",
       deleteDate: ""
    },
    {
       name: "Group2",
       deleteDate: ""
    },
    {
       name: "Group3",
       deleteDate: 18/11/2019""
    }
 ]
}
```

What i want is to get the main element with the groups that have `deleteDate` empty. For this example, i should get this:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "jdflores",
  groups: [
    {
       name: "Group1",
       deleteDate: ""
    },
    {
       name: "Group2",
       deleteDate: ""
    }
 ]
}
```

Is it possible with `@Query`?

Answer (score 0):

Not, MongoDB is a BD not relational, @query is used when your BD is relational you can use findBydeleteDate(String search)